# trying to run php artisan tinker returns error "file_exists(): Unable to find the wrapper "hoa" "

Tags: php, laravel, tinker

I'm trying to open tinker in a Laravel project, but when I run `php artisan tinker` I get this error:

```
ErrorException
file_exists(): Unable to find the wrapper "hoa" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?
```

I can't find everything similar error online, I found only similar errors but with 'wrapper http' .
Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Could this be due to custom code or a library you've imported?

I often find that if I add things to the ServiceProvider or Kernel, they run before many of the artisan commands, and if I've failed to perform the proper "if" checks first, it fails.

I suppose the question I would have in return would be; Is this a fresh Laravel install or have you got custom code and libraries running? I would check there, try removing libraries you've added, HOA from my searching doesn't appear to default to Laravel.

*— Happy to revise my answer should more detail be provided*

Answer (score 0):

Solved with this command founded [on github](https://github.com/Roboroads/laravel-tinker/issues/159):

```
composer require psy/psysh:0.11.2 --dev
```

Comment: The latest release has a fix. Composer update!